# Refusal of Schengen visa by the French embassy in Manila

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

We gifted our daughter an all-expense paid trip to Europe, with the initial stop in London before going to the Schengen member states. Since Paris is the first planned entry to the Schengen countries, she applied with the French Embassy in Manila. She has a UK visa stamped in her passport. Since she is unemployed and we are paying for her full trip for a month, and I am also traveling with her, we have given our support letter addressed to the consul and our financial documents showing our capacity to pay for everything. After losing 2 straight pregnancies, we thought this will give her a break she needed plus she will be traveling with me and my husband will later join us.

Her visa was refused by the French embassy for the following reasons:

> - The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable
> - Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.

She submitted all her flight tickets, hotel accommodations, cruise confirmation and all documents that would show where she will be and that at the end of the trip she will be flying back to the Philippines.

Although it was stated that she can appeal the refusal and the address to send the appeal was in France, will it be better to submit instead a new application rather than make an appeal? I don't know how long the response will be and we are scheduled to leave on May 1 from the Philippines.

All her tickets and accommodations are paid since I am traveling with her. I am a US citizen so I don't need a visa.